# Is there a way to grab all issues in a specific repo that exclude a certain label using GitHub's API?

Tags: github, github-api

You can currently do this via the search UI with syntax like -label:bug, but it doesn't *look* like there is an easy way to do this straight from the [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [`/search/issues`](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues) with its `q` parameter:

> The `q` search term can also contain any combination of the supported issue search qualifiers:
>
> …
>
> `labels` Filters issues or pull requests based on their labels.

[`labels` supports `-` as you have described](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/#search-by-the-labels-on-an-issue).

Comment: I don't believe ```-labels``` works with ```https://api.github.com/repos/.../.../issues?...```.

Comment: @Someguywhocodes, as far as I know it only works with `/search/issues`. The documentation for [List issues for a repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository) makes no mention of `-labels`.

Comment: @Someguywhocodes, you're right that it should be a different question. I'm not aware of any way to exclude issues with a particular label other than filtering them out in your own code.